# Generic business layer design with repository pattern with c# (how)

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am using a repository design with web applications (repository (data layer) exposing model (objects) to the business layer which is then consumed to the data layer (ui).  Objects or lists of objects are passed between the layers with this type of implementation.

I am finding my business layer is a becoming a series of manager type classes which all have common GetAll, GetById, Save, Delete type methods.  This is very common with a number of very small simple objects.  This is the area of concern or opportunity for improvement (the series of smaller business manager classes).  I am looking for options to avoid the whole series of smaller business manager classes mapping to the smaller objects which only do get/save/delete object.

The bigger objects which are closer to the functionality to the application have a number of methods in addition to the get/save/delete type methods (these manager classes are ok).

I am thinking there is a design pattern or implementation which will allow me to have one manager class which resides in the business layer which would accept an object as a parameter of a particular object type and the get/save/delete methods respectively know the type of repository object to spin up and pass the object to it for its operation.

The benefit here would be that I can have one generic manager class to pass save/delete/get's for smaller type objects to the appropriate repository class thereby reducing the many smaller manager classes.

Ideas on how to accomplish this?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not go that way. The business layer classes can be as simple as code that forwards to the data layer, and it is true that they can be annoying to write, but they exist for a couple  of reasons: validation, security, taking some actions based on business rules.

If you try to make a generic business layer, it will hard to include all the various things that a business class could do. The generic business layer will become much more complex than the one you currently have. Testing will be much harder. Adding a new business rule will be hard, too.

Sorry, this is not what you wanted to read, but I have already gone the route of generic systems and have always had lots of regrets.

Comment: I very much appreciate your insight and experience.  Sounds like you have thought along the same lines and came to the above conclusion.  Good information. ty

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a repository (or a dao), is to further abstract data access concerns away from the business layer in order to simplify that layers focus on the "business" of a given domain.

That said, there *are* many common plumbing type of concerns that are reuseable across different applications, some of which do lend themselves to a supertype in the business layer. Consider the cross cutting concern of being able to retrieve a given business entity by some Id from a database, and you *might* come to the conclusion that it is in fact *useful* to have an Id property in a business layer supertype. It might even be useful if entities considered that Id when determining equality. Etc..

Now I do believe that Timores is right in principal and trying to write one application that fits all domains is both incredibly painful and totally fruitless, but I also beleive the the art of the profession is knowing how to use a variety of tools and when to apply which one, and having some core infrastructure code should be in your tool belt.

For a good idea of a framework concept for a web app that has been road tested, take a look at [SharpArch](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/).

HTH,
Berryl